# How to edit css style in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am planning to change a component to required but the component is a shared component so it won't take effect on my HTML view. How do you make your component to required?

**register.component.html**

```
<app-dropdown-multi-select-search fxFlex *ngIf="(register$ | async)?.skills"
                                          [dataList]="(register$ | async)?.skills" [placeHolder]="'Skills'"
                                          [multiSelectDropdown]="true" [searchItem]="true"
                                          (selectedItemEmitted)="handleSelectChange($event)" 
                                          [isRequired]="true">
        </app-dropdown-multi-select-search>
```

**dropdown-multi-select-search.component.ts**

```
@Input()
public isRequired = false;

if(this.isRequired == true) {
  this.isRequired
}
```

**dropdown-multi-select-search.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="dataList">
  <mat-select #multiSelect [placeholder]="placeHolder" name="multi-select-dropdown" 
  [multiple]="multiSelectDropdown" (selectionChange)="onSelect($event)" [isRequired]="false">
<mat-option>
```

I don't know what to put inside my if condition. Inside it I want the component to be required once I set it to "true".

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple add `required` attribute binding to your `mat-select` like

```
 <mat-select #multiSelect [placeholder]="placeHolder" name="multi-select-dropdown" 
  [multiple]="multiSelectDropdown" (selectionChange)="onSelect($event)" [required]="isRequired">
```

In ts file you don't need extra code just `@Input` is fine so it should be

```
@Input() isRequired = false;
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-h8kyka)

Comment: But how do you set it to true in calling the required in my register component? I need to output that required in my register component in order to add * to my mat select.
dropdown-multi-select-search.component.html /.ts is a global component. It is also being used to other modules. That's why it's part of the shared component. If I add the required in my mat-select, It will affect other modules using that component.

Comment: @Ren you are already doing that right way `[isRequired]="true">`